# Where is the heap?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

I understand that in Linux the `mm_struct` describes the memory layout of a process. I also understand that the `start_brk` and `brk` mark the start and end of the heap section of a process respectively.

Now, this is my problem: I have a process, for which I wrote the source code, that allocates 5.25 GB of heap memory using `malloc`. However, when I examine the process's `mm_sruct` using a kernel module I find the value of  is equal to 135168. And this is different from what I expected: I expected  `brk - start_brk` to be equal slight above 5.25 GB.

So, what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: @hcs beat me to it. I suggest reading http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/ in which it says "In Linux, if you request a large block of memory via malloc(), the C library will create such an anonymous mapping instead of using heap memory. ‘Large’ means larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, 128 kB by default and adjustable via mallopt()". The whole article is worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice the following in the [manpage for `malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

> Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2). When allocating blocks of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc() implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping using mmap(2). MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is adjustable using mallopt(3). Allocations performed using mmap(2) are unaffected by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).

So it sounds like `mmap` is used instead of the heap.

Comment: Thanks hcs and @Rob Jinman. Now the question is where is that memory described in the 'mm_struct'?